# Combining に/で particles with 等【など】(or other "etc." stand-ins)

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

I was recently trying to make an **open-ended** enumeration of places in a construction that would require the use of a に particle. E.g.:

> AやBに行こう

or even:

> A[and the like]に行こう

Preferably using a stronger indicator of open-endedness, such as 等 (to me や only has a weak implication of other possibilities, whereas here I want to convey the idea of "places like A [or B]"). But then I realised that the combination of に and 等 did not sound quite right, and even if it was, I had no idea how it would go (`Aに等`? `A等に`?)...

Thus my question:

Can 等 (or a suitably similar word for "and the like") ever be used with a に/で construction? (not necessarily just locations... Tools or "means" as well: `AやBで行こう`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A particle normally follows `など`.

`を` and `に` are marked as optional (my dictionary puts them in parenthesis).

> For tools: フォークやスプーンなど`で`食べる人もいる。 "There are also people who eat it with things like forks and spoons."
>
> For places: 夏休みはXやYなど(に)行きましょうか。"Shall we go to places like X or Y for the summer vacation?"

Interestingly, my dictionary says that if the particles precede `など`,　the sentence is given a derogatory meaning. (`が`, `を` and `は` cannot precede `など`)

> 箸でなど食べられない。　"We can't eat with the damned chopsticks."

---

Alternatively I think you can try:

> For places: Xのような場所 "Places like X"
>
> For tools: Xのような道具　"Tools like X"
>
> And by extension: XのようなY "Y like X" for other categories of things you might think of.

Comment: `ホーク` should be `フォーク`. You are not making the necessary discinction between `A, etc.` (includes A) and `things like A` (usually does not include A).

Answer (score 7):

It is okay to say `などに` and `などで`, but they may sound slightly formal nowadays. A more casual way of saying it is using `とか`: `とかに` and  `とかで`.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Are you saying that 等に would sound *more* formal than just 等 in a sentence?

Comment: @Dave With or without `に`, `等` sounds **slightly** formal. If you read `等` as 'tou', it is even more formal.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean... In that case I am fine with the same level of formality as 等.