# 「恨んでなどいません」についての文法

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-など

## 日本語

文法教材で見たこの文

> 「あなたには感謝こそすれ、**恨んでなど**いません」

の後半の意味と使い方がよくわかりません。

教科書によると、「恨んでなどいません」は  I have no ill feelings と翻訳されます。

それは「恨んでいることなどがない」という意味ですか？ここの恨んでは名詞ですか？でも、そうではないと思います。名詞だったら、など**ありません** になると推測します。

「食べてなどいません」や「悔やんでなどいません」とかは使われていますか？

## English

Question: 恨んでなどいません What is the meaning of this phrase, how to use the など particle?

So I stumbled upon this phrase from a Grammar book

> 「あなたには感謝こそすれ、**恨んでなど**いません」

and I don't understand the latter part of the sentence. The provided English translation says that it means 'Despite what happened, I appreciate your kindness and I have no ill feelings.'

Now, I was confused whether 恨んでなどいません means 恨んでいることはない.
And I misunderstood that 恨んで might be a noun, which leads to the next question that if it is a noun, then why shouldn't it be 恨んでなどありません (No such things like 恨んで).

Also, do we use 食べてなどいません and such?

Comment: is `感謝こそすれ` like that in the original?

Comment: Yes Igor. They say it means 感謝はしているけれど、絶対に。。。

Comment: その動詞、本当に「悩む」でしょうか。

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2347/9831 ・ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43506/9831

Comment: @Igor 「～こそすれ」はちょっと硬い表現で、→ 　https://www.weblio.jp/content/こそすれ / https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/こそすれ-koso-sure/

Comment: 間違いました。その動詞は「恨む」です。

Comment: @JoisBack Will it be alright if you provide an English translation for your question?

Comment: @FlonneLightberry Hold my beer.

Comment: @JoisBack okay, I'll upvote your question then. I'm interested in your Grammar question, so a good translation is definitely a big plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

明鏡国語辞典を引用しますと、その「など」は、

> など〘副助詞〙
>   ❸ 軽んじる気持ちをこめて取り上げる。
>   ㋐ 《否定的な表現を伴って》取るに足りないものとして取り上げて否定の意を強める。「あなた**など**には分からない」「表彰**など**受けたくもない」「あいつに**など**負けるものか」「泣いて**など**いられない」

という意味で使われています。

「恨んでいません」「泣いていられない」「食べていません」「悔やんでいない」などの、「恨む」「泣く」「食べる」等の行為を[取]{と}るに[足]{た}りないものとして[軽]{かろ}んじる気持ちを[込]{こ}めながら、否定の意味を強めて「[恨]{うら}んで**など**いません」「泣いて**など**いられない」「食べて**など**いません 」「[悔]{く}やんで**など**いない」のように使います。「恨んでなんかいません」「泣いてなんかいられない」「悔やんでなんかいない」などとだいたい同じ意味になります。

これらの「恨んで」「食べて」「悔やんで」は名詞ではありません。「恨んでいません」「悔やんでいない」などの打消しに、「など」が挿入されている形です。

Comment: Chocolate san Thank you. But can you explain in English what 取るに足りないものとして means? And what does that 転じる気持ち mean? Does it mean a 'change in feeling?' Like trying to show a contradiction?

Comment: @Jois 取るに足りないもの means "(lit.) not worth bothering about / considering" -> "unimportant, insignificant". And [軽]{かろ}んじる気持ち means "a feeling of making light of / belittling".

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the reply in English.

You can think of this phrase as an emphasized version of `悩んでいません`. More often you might see `は` inserted in the middle, like 悩んで**は**いません.

So the overall meaning is something like "I am not worried *at all*" or, more literally, "I do not do things **such as** worrying" (about whatever happened, I assume).

See also [What does the "〜やしない" conjugation mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/what-does-the-%E3%82%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-conjugation-mean)　about a similar construct.

Comment: Thanks Igor! I really appreciate your answer in English, no worries. (悩んでなどいません lol) So from Chocolate's answer あなたなどには分からない will mean, people like you( make a derogatory face) won't understand, right?