# What is the meaning of 一切気にかけようともなさらない in this sentence?

Tags: translation

I am trying to understand the sentence 人の批難など一切気にかけようともなさらない。However, I have not been able to parse かけようとも into any words and particles I can identify or find in a dictionary.

So I want to know
1) what are the words/particles in this piece of the sentence, and
2) what does 一切気にかけようともなさらない mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[気にかける](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase which means "to care about", "to worry about". `一切 (+ ない)` is "(not) at all". This 一切 is a stiff [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) that works like まったく. `よう + と + する` is "to try to do ～", and なさる is an honorific version of する. [など](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60238/5010) and も are for emphasis.

- 人の批難を気にかける: to worry about other's criticism
- 人の批難を気にかけようとする: to try to worry about other's criticism
- 人の批難を気にかけようとなさる: (honorific version of the above)
- 人の批難を**一切**気にかけようとなさら**ない**: not to try to care about other's criticism at all
- 人の批難**など**一切気にかけようと**も**なさらない: (emphatic version of the above)